# Using Local reference breaks while create a staging/production build (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Following are the template code and the error I get while creating the build although it works fine when I do `ng serve`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control unit-price"  name="unit_price" [(ngModel)]="item.unit_price" #unitPrice="ngModel" required>
           <span class="small text-danger" *ngIf="!unitPrice?.valid && unitPrice?.touched ">Field is Required</span>
```

[image]

Any thing I am missing ?

Will I have to declare that property in component ?

Answer (score 0):

On my UnderStanding There is no **unitPrice** field inside the **item** object please verify the item object that you had mentioned in the [(ngModel)].

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, convert this: `#unitPrice="ngModel"` to this: `#unit_price="ngModel"` in your code.